# IE displays error statement when trying to remove svg raphael element-

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, raphael

I am using raphael to display lines that have to draw dynamically between elements not visible on the "paper" drawing surface- ie connect the dots- 2 rows of dots, 1 above one below the paper area with a simple line drawn between them. I can draw the lines in IE and all other browsers  and I can remove them in every browser except IE (tested on v9 and v11).

I get the line reference via:
    var tID = _currVars.myVars.tileObjects[tClickedID].myLine;
    var tLine = document.getElementById(tID);

and remove by:
    tLine.remove();

in IE only I get this error:
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'remove'

jquery-1.10.2.min.js, line 5 character 14073

I am a noob to raphael and svg, so I am unsure if I am removing this correctly- sometimes IE is a stickler for correct syntax, etc. Again, works great in everything but IE.

Thanks!

Comment: Raphael has its own DOM structure, so you need to remove that element through Raphael, eg: `paper.getById(rap_id).remove();` where `rap_id` is the ID assigned by Raphel.

Comment: That worked great- Thanks! i got the id i assigned and compared it to find the one I wanted to get rid of, then deleted it via your method:  Raphaels ids are all numbers like 0,1,2,3 etc  -----       var tLineToRemove = 0;

_rPaper.forEach(function (el) 
{
  if(el[0].id === tID){
   tLineToRemove = el.id;
  }

});


_rPaper.getById(tLineToRemove).remove();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raphael has its own DOM structure, so you need to remove that element through Raphael, eg: `paper.getById(rap_id).remove();` where `rap_id` is the ID assigned by Raphael.

Note: adding it as an answer so others would know about it (in case they missed the comments).